# Angular 2 Pagination not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement angular2-datatable from https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable/blob/master/README.md in to my application. But for some reason the `rowsOnPage` is not taking the number I assign to it.

For e.g. when I say show 5 records on a page, it shows all the records. I don't know what I am missing. Can someone please help me resolve it.

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" [mfData]="products  | SearchPipe : searchText" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <mfDefaultSorter by="gt">GT</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th>
        <mfDefaultSorter by="name_e">Name E</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th class="no-sort hidden-sm-down">
        <mfDefaultSorter by="name_z">Name Z</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products | SearchPipe : searchText">
      <td><a [routerLink]="['/app/master/products',product.gtin]">{{product.gt}}</a></td>
      <td>{{product.name_e}}</td>
      <td>{{product.name_z}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/app/master/productEdit', product.gt]">
                                Edit
                            </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="!products.length">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6">No Records Found</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="(products | SearchPipe : searchText).length === 0">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6">No matches</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12">
        <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 15]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change you `ngFor`. In official example they are using

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
```

But you have put in `ngFor` different data

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products | SearchPipe : searchText">
```

Have a look on [demo from documentation](http://plnkr.co/edit/PxBaZs?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But when I add that mf. in front of my products, then my data is not getting loaded into the table

Comment: What do you mean "in from of my products"?
What error do you have in console?
I think that you need to use mf.data explicitly. Not `mf.products`

Comment: I dont get any error.
In my component class I have the product data which gets from the backend<br/>
`export class ProductComponent  implements OnInit {<br/>

  title: string;
  products: IProduct[] = [];

getProducts() {
    console.log('getProducts() retrieved products');
    this.productDataService.getProducts().subscribe((product_data: IProduct[]) =>{
        this.products = product_data;
    }),
    (err:any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('retrieved products');

  }`

Comment: @Denis...thanks you your comment helped me to resolve the issue!!

Comment: @ZAJ no problem ) I'm glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying late but this for future readers.
In my case, I was having same issue due wrong way of specifying value for `[mfRowsOnPage]`.

The way I have specified the value

`[mfRowsOnPage]="'5'"`

Correct way to specify the value

`[mfRowsOnPage]="5"`